# How to add 2 icon in the left of Side Bar Menu?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I want to add 2 icons, add new child menu icon, and delete menu icon.
But  the problem is when i add the icon on the left, i can't click the icon, when i want to click it will click the menu.

This is the mockup,

[image]

And this is the code,

```
<ul class="nav menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#"> Widgets&nbsp;<em class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></em>&nbsp;<em class="fa fa-minus pull-right"></em></a>

            </li>


        </ul>
```

And this is the result,

[image]

What i need is when i click the add icon it will go to add form, and if i click delete icon it will delete the menu.

Comment: and how that is related with PHP, I wonder?

Comment: sorry i edited it, can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: There is free HTML CSS menu present over internet in which you can add and remove menu OR submenu. I remember few years back I worked on it. I don't remember link.But you can find it over internet for sure.